# Cycles texture with alpha doesn't work after using AnimAll for animating UVs

Tags: animation, transparency

I need a texture to be animated with AnimAll and have transparency at the same time. Is this possible?

Here is the .blend file. It is the bird that encounters the problem. I'm trying to make its wings flap.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2VC7joyS00fNUdPYWk1M0ZoWTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The textures are missing from the file, can you save the file with packed textures?